# Is there a method to change the height of a widget by clicking on its twin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a simple class that creates cards that expand when I click on them, and shrink when I click them again.
Is it possible to make sure that when one expands the others shrink automatically? Thanks to anyone who will answer me.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: IlMioTema(),
      home: PageOne(),
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: arancio4,
          title: Text('Hercules'),
        ),
        body: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 85, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CardDue(titolo:'ONE', colore1: blu1),
              CardDue(titolo:'TWO', colore1: Tiffanycolor),
              CardDue(titolo:'THREE', colore1: Tiffanycolor),
            ],
          )
      ),
    ),
);
  }
}

class CardDue extends StatefulWidget{
  final String titolo;
  final Color colore1;

  CardDue({Key key, this.titolo, this.colore1}): super(key:key);

  @override
  _CardDueState createState() => _CardDueState();
}

class _CardDueState extends State<CardDue> {
double height = 120;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selected = !selected;
          });
          if (!selected) {
            setState(() {
              height = 120;
            });
          } else {
           setState(() {
             altezza = 400;
           });
          }
    },
    child: AnimatedContainer(
      height: height,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(selected ? 0 : 10),
        color: widget.colore1,
      ),
      child: ...
```

it works correctly for modifying itself, but I can't reset the heights of the other CardDue.
is there a way to change individual widget states or would it work with sharedpreference?
Thanks to anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to change the height only one of the card is to define the function individually. Here what I did:

- I convert the **PageOne** class into Statefull widget and **CardDue** class to Stateless widget.
- **CardDue** has two extra parameter in constructor, that takes a *function* and a *bool* variable.

why I did ?

having a separate bool variable for each **CardDue** class make sure only one of them is true. If its true, we simply set other two bool variable to *false*.

Here's the code:

```
class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  
  bool card1 = false;
  bool card2 = false;
  bool card3 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // backgroundColor: arancio4,
        title: Text('Hercules'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 85, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CardDue(
                    titolo: 'ONE',
                    colore1: Colors.red,
                    selected: card1,
                    function: () {
                      setState(() {
                        card1 = !card1;
                        card2 = false;
                        card3 = false;
                      });
                    }),
                CardDue(
                    titolo: 'TWO',
                    colore1: Colors.blue,
                    selected: card2,
                    function: () {
                      setState(() {
                        card2 = !card2;
                        card1 = false;
                        card3 = false;
                      });
                    }),
                CardDue(
                    titolo: 'THREE',
                    colore1: Colors.yellow,
                    selected: card3,
                    function: () {
                      setState(() {
                        card3 = !card3;
                        card2 = false;
                        card1 = false;
                      });
                    }),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardDue extends StatelessWidget {
  final String titolo;
  final Color colore1;
  final bool selected;
  final Function function;

  CardDue({Key key, this.titolo, this.colore1, this.selected, this.function})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: function,
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          height: selected ? 400 : 120,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          curve: Curves.decelerate,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(selected ? 0 : 10),
            color: colore1,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

let me know if this work.

Comment: brilliant! putting a function as a parameter... now i try

Comment: unfortunately I know that the function is not executed, clicking several times on the same card always gives me selected to false. its status does not change

Comment: only the parentheses next to function() were missing when it was called ... best solution